# How do you help people learn logic?

Tags: logic

People who are not IT, more specifically programmers, do not have a good way of solving problems. They simply do not think like us, programmers, who have a good [logic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logic).
I have been asked too many times what I would recommend them to improve their logic which would eventually help with day-to-day professional problems. Things that come up to my mind are good puzzles, math problems and etc.

Having said that, what would you recommend and why? Books, sites, articles ?

Comment: why are questions closed for being "not programming related" even when they are tagged as "not-programming-related".  I think this question could be important given that these people are trying to improve their critical thinking skills such that they can easier solve problems.

Comment: Yes, why it is closed as "Not programming relaed"? It IS programming related. I should be closed as "Not a real question" :)

Comment: Don't close this. It's an extremely pertinent question.

Comment: However, the question title should be edited to something more relevant.

Comment: voted to reopen.  I think people are reacting more to the eccentric title than to the question.

Comment: The title should be changed to something else a little more on subject.  I would vote to reopen if I could...

Comment: I thought about the title just to be a little bit more creative and fun as well. It's a shame some people don't like these type of question as they might help others to improve their critical thinking.

Comment: More power to you Andre...it's a catchy title that leads to a good question

Comment: however this really smells like a wiki question...

Comment: Just to make this clear. I didn't vote as "blatantly offensive" but as "Not a real Question". I don't know why was that the status. Having said that... This is not a real question anyway.

Comment: @Oscar Reyes...how is this not a question?  why don't you back up your point?  Andre is asking "how do you teach someone logic so they can become better problem solvers and thus better programmers".

Comment: It's a valid question that needs to be turned into a wiki: How do you train your students/colleagues to make them fundamentally better programmers?

Comment: Ates Goral, how do you convert it to a wiki?

Comment: @Ates and Casey: Agreed. Can we convert it to a wiki and change the title as well?

Comment: Question is badly worded. Author states that IT people have "good logic" and ask "how to teach non-IT" people. 1) logic is not tied to job - there are stupid programmers/wise janitors 2) If author as a programmer has a "good logic" he probably knows where/how to learn (thereafter teach) it.

Comment: "do not think like us" - how do typical programmers think?

Comment: @Andre: I think only the question owner (and probably a moderator?) has the privilege to change a question into a wiki. Try the edit link under the tags for your question.

Comment: That's funny: Make it wiki, change the title, and re-word the question :P  ... and change the topic in the process?  Isn't that too much?

Comment: @Casey: There is not a good answer to this. All of the possible answers are subject to argument and are very subjective.  The questions of SO should go more in terms of programming, code, algorithms. etc. This is not a general forum. Still, it is community driven, so if you vote to reopen I ...

Comment: ... wont close it again. Is up to you. Finally here's a link that may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/321618/where-can-i-ask-questions-that-arent-programming-questions

Comment: @aku Yes I know but that's my own view. If there is a site like stackoverflow.com where people help people and people learn with people, that's probably where I would post a question like this to look for other peolple's opinion ....

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not within the bounds of discussion as described in the help center.

Answer (score 6):

Related article on [codinghorror.com](http://codinghorror.com):

[Separating Programming Sheep from Non-Programming Goats](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/000635.html)

> All teachers of programming find that
>   their results display a 'double hump'.
>   It is as if there are two populations:
>   those who can [program], and those who
>   cannot [program], each with its own
>   independent bell curve. Almost all
>   research into programming teaching and
>   learning have concentrated on
>   teaching: change the language, change
>   the application area, use an IDE and
>   work on motivation. **None of it works,
>   and the double hump persists.**

Quick takeaway from the above excerpt: The speculation is that whatever you do won't work if a person can't program to begin with.

> To write a computer program you have
>   to come to terms with this, to accept
>   that whatever you might want the
>   program to mean, the machine will
>   blindly follow its meaningless rules
>   and come to some meaningless
>   conclusion. In the test the consistent
>   group showed a pre-acceptance of this
>   fact: they are capable of seeing
>   mathematical calculation problems in
>   terms of rules, and can follow those
>   rules wheresoever they may lead. The
>   inconsistent group, on the other hand,
>   **looks for meaning where it is not**. The
>   blank group knows that it is looking
>   at meaninglessness, and refuses to
>   deal with it.

My proposed tongue-in-cheek solution: Convert them to atheism/nihilism. That way, they won't try to look for meaning where it is not [sic] and perhaps then come to terms with binary.

Comment: For some reason I'm now singing the Cake lyric "Sheep go to Heaven, goats go to Hell!"

Answer (score 3):

Most people who don't think like geeks don't really WANT to think like geeks either.

But part of solving a problem is breaking it down into smaller parts, each of which is an easy problem to solve.  If they can learn how to break up a problem into managable chunks, they'll be well on their way to at least improving some parts of solving a geek-like problems.

As for logic, remind them of the law of non-contradiction: A != !A.  A thing cannot be true and false at the same time.  We spend too much of our time not even trying to think straight.

Comment: There's nothing *geeky* about thinking logically.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend Sudoku and games like [Brain Age](http://www.brainage.com/launch/what.jsp) for most non-programmers.

Answer (score 2):

I had flunked first semester programming about 3 times,then I tried an online course employing  "programmed" learning methods in desperation.

It helped me get over the "hump" by helping  me understand programming (I believe) by providing the context and motivations for some of the more common (really simple to you folks) programming logic constructs.

Hours of practice "running" toy programs on paper for different problems afterwards finally ended my absolute confusion on this subject matter.

The link to the free, CS intro course employing this programmed approach that I had used (while ditching my regular lecturer) is :

http://chortle.ccsu.edu/CS151/cs151java.html

Still stumped though by exam level problems using stacks and queues and recursion (we used C in our courses but I think it didn't really matter in the final analysis).

In the end, I didn't bother with a CS major as I would have taken forever (probably 2 to 3 yrs more) given my skill level.

I should have paid attention to those puzzle books when I was little. I was more of a LEGO geek then  :)

CS instructors (those who only talk and talk) need to be a little more patient, some of us folks aren't good verbal learners.

Parting thought, we all can't be be great writers, but that doesn't stop one from learning (or teaching one) how to write well. I think the same goes for computer programming in the information age.

Answer (score 1):

People can always improve their problem solving ability with practice, but (imo) only to a degree.  Some people will never think like that.  They just weren't wired that way from birth.  I don't think that we have a lot of control over our innate potential, just what we do with it.

Answer (score 0):

I've found that if you keep thinking and are always trying to solve puzzles, even the stupid little ones, in a neat, interesting, optimized, huge, small, pretty much any way, then you keep yourself sharp.  Also reading other's solutions help point out things that you would not have thought of which in the long run give you this "tool box" of methods that could be applied in similar or even dissimilar situations.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt the wiring is genetic, its more likely to be socially imprinted upon the brain during childhood. Some children do puzzles and others don't, those that do many puzzles will be better prepared, but as Bill the Lizard mentions I think that anyone can re-train their brain to abstract puzzle solving.

Comment: +1 for believing people can change.

Answer (score 0):

I am not that good at logic, I once remember I had a problem where I wanted to remove something from an array, someone came and told me *"why don't you just create a new one but excluding the items you want to remove?"*. I felt really ashamed, I mean, that solution is perfect, after all, every approach would need to iterate on every element, why not simply do that and copy these to a new array but excluding the unwanted ones?

But going back to the question, some of the things I recommend are:

- **Playing Chess** (this really help you in life, if you play it frequently, you will automatically start to consider different alternatives to different problems and reduce them to the very best one)
- **Solving Sudokus** (this is very good for deduction skills)

Another exercise that *really* improved my logic skills was to set an easy programming task, and then try to solve it in 3-5 different ways.

Answer (score -2):

This is one of the best logical fallacy sites I have found on the web.

[Logical Fallacies](http://www.nizkor.org/features/fallacies/)

I would recommend this site to anyone that has an interest in the casual nature of language.  The examples on the site for each kind of logical fallacy are for the most part very good and I guarantee you will learn something.  Forward it along.

nmr

Comment: The [site you linked to](http://www.nizkor.org/features/fallacies/) is terrible, it explains a bunch of things that are common sense and the few useful fallacies are explained badly. The [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fallacy) is more useful and easier to understand.